# K8s, apparent IP of a pod that tries to connect to an external database

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I am trying to access an external postgres from my pod. The problem is that in order to do this, I need to allow in the external database `pg_hba.conf` the "host address"/ "IP" of the pod. It is clear that I can temporarily use the address of the node, e.g. someNode.online-server.cloud.

The problem is that of course, if the pod restarts, it might restart on another node. For the converse problem, I could use a service/endpoint that would provide an anchor for all external traffic to go through... Is there a way to do something like this in my case? I am thinking port forwarding on a host can be both ways, but not sure what to do in K8s.

Comment: One option (probably not the cleanest one out there) is to create an initContainer that registers itself in the external postgres (you'd need to devise a way to do that - CLI?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) that the address field can be a CIDR.

> Specifies the client machine address(es) that this record matches. This field can contain either a host name, an IP address range, or one of the special key words mentioned below.

Therefore, you can add the CIDR of the subnet of your cluster, given the assumption, this is within a private network.

This might look something like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    app             app             192.168.0.0/16          scram-sha-256
```

If this goes through the public web, all pods are likely to go through the same gateway and therefore get the same IP assigned, which you can use.

Alternatively, you can also use a hostname.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. The address of the DB is a public IP because it is running outside of K8s. `pg_hba.conf` is there and specifies what public IPs are allowed to access that DB. The problem is I cannot provide a public IP point as the pod may reside in a number of nodes. I could possibly provide all the nodes names?  I would expect to have at the addres something like [pod ip]

Comment: @ntg, a single pod usually doesnt have a public IP. And your nodes should probably also not have a public IP. Depending on how you have set up your cluster. It is likely that your traffic goes through a gateway. If this is the case, you can use the gateway IP address for your allow rule. In AWS this would be some elastic IP, for example. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html, to understand what I mean.

Comment: For the example EKS, its also more explained here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/creating-a-vpc.html. The concept stays the same, regardless of AWS. *The nodes in private subnets can communicate with the cluster and other AWS services, and pods can communicate outbound to the internet through a NAT gateway (IPv4) or egress-only Internet gateway (IPv6) that is deployed in each Availability Zone. A security group is deployed that denies all inbound traffic and allows all outbound traffic.*

Comment: Ah actually if i get what you are saying the pod will appear to have the gateway IP? I thought that each node would have an IP, but actually that sounds good and would solve my problem :)

Comment: @ntg, yes. Because the pod doesnt have a public ip. So it goes through the gatway which has a public IP to communicate with the outside world. Or to be more precise ,the node the pod is running on is doing that.

Comment: Here you can read also about internet gateway. Again its an AWS example but the concepts are the same everywhere https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

Comment: Just checking though... I logged in (node shell) with lens to two different nodes (same namespace) and tried to get their public IP (`wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain | xargs echo`), and I am getting two different IP addresses... Dont know if that would be the case if I was inside a pod though

Comment: ...the pods also give me a different IP :S ( I think I am on Ionos or Azure, not sure should check...)

Comment: @ntg, then your nodes are exposed directly to the internet. So there is no nat or internet gateway, I guess. Then you may have to list your node ips in the config file. Although I would recommend, changing your setup so that the nodes don't have a public IP, its a secuirty risk.

Comment: thanx, that makes sense. Not my design, and there is a firewall that cuts all incoming traffic but I can see why a gateway would make sense (including solving my problem).

Comment: I think your answer, along with the comments constitutes a valid response to my question.

Comment: @ntg, one last thing. Your database server should probably also not be reachable via public web. It would be good to have a vpn tunnel between your cluster and the network the db is on. Then you could also use a private IP cidr.